# SQL Server--Is it possible to work around using a temporary table for a query that filters based on an alias case column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to alter a base query that selects data from several joined tables, and filters out rows based on the `CASE WHEN` below. The result set is to be returned as follows:

- If all of the rows return 0 in the `CASE` column, return one line with '0' in the `OVERDUE` column (the "return one line" portion is taken care of by `DISTINCT`.)
- If any of the rows return 1 for the `CASE` column, return one line with '1' in the `OVERDUE` column.

The base is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*,
CASE WHEN t3.MTemp > t3.MTempLimit
    then 1
        when t3.TotHours > t3.THoursLimit
            then 1
            else 0
end  [Overdue]
  from table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 on t1.ResNo = t2.ResNo and t1.PCode = t2.PCode 
LEFT JOIN table_3 t3 on t2.RepJobNo = t3.RepJobNo
LEFT JOIN table_4 t4 on t4.TypeID = t2.RepType
    WHERE t2.RepStat = 1
```

The catch is, I've already created a working version of this by using a temp table and doing a `IF EXISTS/ELSE` query on the temp table's `OVERDUE` column. However, I've been informed that this solution may not be useable (due to having to go through certain front-end software).

Is it possible to do a workaround for this that does not involve using a temporary table? I've been making attempts at using both a derived table and CTEs, neither of which have yielded anything usable, due to the fact that one cannot use `IF/ELSE` clauses after those (which was what I was counting on).

I'm still getting the hang of T-SQL, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the front-end software? Is it some sort of enterprise or reporting software (like Business Objects for example)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the answer to that (though if I did, rest assured I would mention it).  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a simple [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and a couple of CTEs will work:

```
;WITH RS1 as (
  SELECT t1.*,
  CASE WHEN t3.MTemp > t3.MTempLimit
    then 1
        when t3.TotHours > t3.THoursLimit
            then 1
            else 0
  end  [Overdue]
  from table_1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 on t1.ResNo = t2.ResNo and t1.PCode = t2.PCode 
  LEFT JOIN table_3 t3 on t2.RepJobNo = t3.RepJobNo
  LEFT JOIN table_4 t4 on t4.TypeID = t2.RepType
      WHERE t2.RepStat = 1
 ), RS2 as (
     select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Overdue DESC) rn
     from RS1
 )
 select * from RS2 where rn = 1
```

(There's no need for a `DISTINCT` now that we're only returning one row)

Comment: Thanks a million.  I would have been happy with a nudge in the right direction, but this looks exactly like what I was after.  I'm still fairly new to many aspects of T-SQL, so I had no idea about the "row_number" piece.

Answer (score 1):

In general any temporary table referenced in another query can simply be substituted for as follow, so that this:

```
insert #temp
select -- definition of temptable
;
select ... 
from #temp
join ...
```

becomes

```
select
from ( 
  -- definition of temptable
) temp
join ...
```